# Why can I not pass a function call (rather than a function reference or an anonymous function) to setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Please ignore the fact that this code achieves nothing and apologies for what's probably an inane question!

I understand that I cannot pass a function call into `setTimeout()` as the first argument, but *why* can I not do that?

```
let names = ['Andy', 'Ross', 'David'];

function printer (name) {
 console.log(name);
}

names.forEach(name => setTimeout(printer(name), 1000);
```

Result:

```
Andy
timers.js:327
    throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');
    ^
```

I can solve the problem by instead using a reference to `printer` and using `bind()` to send `name` along with it, but why must I take these extra steps?

```
let names = ['Andy', 'Ross', 'David'];

function printer (name) {
  console.log(name);
}

names.forEach(name => setTimeout(printer.bind(null, name), 1000));
```

Result:

```
Andy
Ross
David
```

Comment: because setTimeout should receive a callback which should be called later

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the order of execution. If you pass a function call to setTimeout, the function will be executed immediately, i.e. the function is put on javascript's execution stack immediately.

If you pass a function name, i.e. a reference to a function, the function is only put in the javascript thread's execution stack once the timer finishes.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){printer(name)}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` should take a function as its first argument.

Please refer:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Here you are passing the result of the function as the first argument which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
setTimeout(printer, 1000, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of passing a function reference is to use callbacks.

```
names.forEach(name => setTimeout(function() {
    printer(name);
}, 1000));
```

callbacks contains reference to the function.

```
setTimeout(callbackFunction, milliseconds);
```